# Jquery mobile event delay

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a little dashboard in HTML+jquery mobile which contains a number of buttons, sliders, checkboxes, number inputs, etc.

Obviously I want to connect the actions (changes to fields etc) to calls to the backend. However, if someone pushes a switch button three times in a row qucikly I don't want to trigger three backend calls as those button clicks actually have hardware consequences.

What I want is for each of these buttons/sliders/checkboxes to trigger the backend calls only after a X second delay (when I consider the user has decided that the entered number, slider or checkbox has the value they really want).

What would be the most elegant way of achieving something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want an x second delay after a user stops entering data, then use a set time out and an update function. It will, of course, cause the user to experience lag.

```
var seconds = 3, timer;

$(function(){

    var update = function(){
        $("#response").append("<p>run updates!</p>");
    }

    $("#slider-1").change(function(){
        if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(update, seconds * 1000);
    });

});
```

Here's a jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/aEftd/4/

Comment: That would work but I want the last value of the slider or the checkbox (e.g. 3 second after the last change) to be considered and be sent to the backend.

Comment: upopple, still not what I need unfortunately. In my case, the user should be able to fiddle with the slider for example for 5 minutes, but only as he leaves it alone for 3 seconds or more the call to the backend is triggered with the last value.

Answer (score 0):

When I was writing some `ajax` calls , I disabled the button till the backend call either passed or failed.  Also, there's a `.one()` method in jQuery that may help depending on where you want to go with it.

```
$("#input").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, disabling is not what I want. I would like the user to be left to adjust the slider for example and then e.g. 3 seconds after the last change, the event should be triggered. I looked at the .one definition but I don't think I could use it for that.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most elegant way but it should work for your case:

```
var flag=1;
function resumeEvents() {
    //reset flag to 1 to accept the input again after time
    flag=1;
}

$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        if(flag==1){
            //perform your task 
            alert("Task performed");
            //set flag to 0 so it doesn't accept more clicks
            flag=0;
            //time to pause before next click is accepted.
            setTimeout(resumeEvents, 3000);
        }
    });

});
```

Fiddle with your scenario:
http://jsfiddle.net/bmRsr/

Comment: Hi Usman, I need something slightly different: I want the last value of the slider or the checkbox (e.g. 3 second after the last change) to be considered and be sent to the backend. This code immediately triggers the event and then prevents the next one for X seconds.